# Understanding the constructor in magento PHP files

Tags: product, magento-1, magento-enterprise, products-management, wishlist

I have something like this in list.phtml __('Add to Wishlist') ?> and I want to know which constructor and which PHP class file is it calling for ?

Comment: Constructors in PHP are `__constructor`. `__` is a normal method! And be careful, magento introduces `_constructor` (one _), this is a "normal" method too, but called by the `__constructor` :-)

Answer (score 2):

The block classes are extended from the **Mage_Core_Block_Abstract**, in this class the function __() calls the translator to translate the supplied text:

```
/**
     * Translate block sentence
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $expr = new Mage_Core_Model_Translate_Expr(array_shift($args), $this->getModuleName());
        array_unshift($args, $expr);
        return Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate($args);
    }
```